# Python set literals didn't work on numpy unique array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, set, unique

I tried to use `python` set literals on `numpy` `unique` like

```
import numpy as np
# col_value_series is a series of strings
# it doesn't run
uniques = {np.unique(col_value_series)}

# it works
uniques = set(np.unique(col_value_series))
```

I have to use `set` instead of `{}` to get a set of unique values, so what's the different? Are they not the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not the same.

`{np.unique(col_value_series)}` (or, generally, `{x}`) is a set of one element. For this to work, the element `x` must be hashable [[glossary](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html)], which it is not. Consider:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: {np.array([1])}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f73a363763ae> in <module>()
----> 1 {np.array([1])}

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

`set(np.unique(col_value_series))` (or `set(x)`) is a set of elements taken from an iterable `x`. For this to work, the argument `x` must be iterable, and its elements must be hashable. These conditions are met, so it works.

```
In [3]: set(np.array([1]))
Out[3]: {1}
```